# Looking for a solution that allows company wide, rules based, attachment download for Office 365 emails

Tags: microsoft-exchange, office365, email-attachments

We are looking to transition from on premise Exchange to Office 365. We are looking to find an application that can replace a utility that we have in place. MapiLabs [Attachment Save for Exchange](https://www.mapilab.com/exchange/attachment_save/).

This utility is similar to the built in Outlook rules, with some key differences. First, it works with Exchange not Outlook, so we can create centralized mail processing rules for the entire company. Second, you can create fairly granular rules to automatically download specific attachments to a selected folder without human intervention.

Does anything exist that would work in a similar way for Office 365 email systems? I have seen a mention of MS Power Automate can be setup to replicate some of these functions. Anything else?